Why isnt my function displaying the table I have created using a for loop to the front end?
I'm trying to create a function that returns the 12 times table of a given number that a user submits through a form. The user inputs a number through an input box and clicks the times button.
Then a 12 times table for that number is listed. I'm having trouble outputting the array from the function to the front end page.


function timestable(x) {
  let x = Number(document.userNum.Number.value);
  let table = [];
  for (i = 0; i++; i < 13) {
    value = x * i;
    table.push(value);
  }
  return table;
};
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="userNum">
    Number: <input type="text" name="number1">
    <button onclick="timestable()">Times</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>




By default, buttons have type="submit", so your form is submitting and refreshing the page before the js function can run. You'll want to pass the event to the timestable(e) and then call preventDefault() on the event to prevent the form from submitting. Or you can use type="button" to prevent the form submission.
Also, I see you have defined a parameter x in timestable(), that you immediately overwrite with Number(...).

You're also not updating the DOM at all; your function returns an array, but does nothing with it. And there's no element with name="Number" in your html.

You should also refresh yourself on the syntax for a for-loop.

There are a couple of issues:

You are passing x as a parameter in the timestable function but also
redefine it inside that very same function
The for loop should be written like for (i = 0; i++; i < 13)
You use document.userNum.Number.value in your function but in your
html it is the document.userNum.number1.value element
When you submit a form by default the page will refresh, you can
prevent this behaviour with event.preventDefault(); in the timestable
function

And if you want to display the results which I'm guessing you do you should put the results back into a HTML element like so;
add to timestable():
// Output the times table to the page
        let resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
        resultDiv.innerHTML = table.join("<br>");

add to HTML
<!-- Div to display the times table result -->
<div id="result"></div>

